# How to get string from the form to user Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control for save button which saves data from the form to database. There are 3 inputs as strings which I want the user to define it in the form and get it in the user controls save button click.

Comment: Please post your code sample.  Show us the user control, inputs, and what you have tried.

Comment: We need further clarification please along with what you have tried & what's not working.

Comment: Just `public` them in that `Form` then you'll be able to access them from the user control like: `Form1.Input1`, `Form1.Input2`, `Form1.Input3` ... Good luck.